# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\oop_project\oop_class.php on line 66

Tags: php, prepared-statement

```
//function to add bm
function add_bm($new_url, $email)
{
   $db = $this->dbm;


  $this->new_url = $new_url;
  $this->email = $email;

   $sql = "select * from bookmark where email='$this->valid_user' and bm_URL='$this->new_url'";

    if(!$stmt = $db->conn->query($sql))
        {

          echo "query failed: (" . $db->conn->errno . ") " .$db->conn->error;
        }else{
       //echo "can check";
       //return true;


    //row count
     if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
       echo "<b><br>Sorry ! <br> The URL had already been added . </b> ";
       return false;
      }else{
     //return true;

     // prepare and bind

        $stmt = $db->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO bookmark (email, bm_URL,) VALUES (?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $this->email, $this->new_url);


// set parameters and execute
    if($stmt->execute()){

            $stmt->close();
        $db->conn->close();

        return true;
            }
        }
        }

}
```

Comment: Look at [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Comment: You have a syntax error in your prepared statement, and since you have absolutely no error handling and simply ASSUME that nothing coudl ever go wrong, you take the boolean false returned by the failed prepare and run, causing further chaos.

Comment: Typo `bm_URL,`. You should be binding everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

When you do DB operations, check for errors before you proceed. Otherwise you get unexpected behaviors and puzzling errors such as this.

Your `$stmt->bind_param` isn't working because `$stmt===false` because the previous instruction errored.

```
if(!$stmt = $db->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ...")){
    //something went wrong. This shows the error but handle as appropriate
    die($db->$conn->error);
}
//safe to continue
$stmt->bind_param(...)
```